# Pretty Printing list of lists

Tags: haskell

I have a list of lists:

```
[[5,1,0,0,5,5,0,0],[0,0,1,4,2,0,6,1],[1,1,6,3,0,1,0,0],[1,5,0,0,0,1,1,6]]
```

and a string "wxyz"

I would like to have:
1)

```
w: 5 1 0 0 5 5 0 0
x: 0 0 1 4 2 0 6 1
y: 1 1 6 3 0 1 0 0
z: 1 5 0 0 0 1 1 6
```

I wrote:

```
f c xs = putStrLn (c : ':' : ' ' : concat (intersperse " " $ map show xs))
```

to write one line

and 2)

```
g xxs c = mapM_ (f c) xxs
```

How can I modify 2) to loop through string "wxyz" in order to have 1) ?

Answer (score 9):

Instead of `mapM_`, you can use `zipWithM_` from `Control.Monad`:

```
g xss cs = zipWithM_ f cs xss
```

or, if you change the order of arguments in either `f` or `g` to match, you can do it with less "points":

```
g = zipWithM_ f
```

Also, `concat (intersperse " " ...)` is otherwise known as `unwords ...`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` and `uncurry`:

```
g xxs c = mapM_ (uncurry f) (zip xxs c)
```